# SimpleDateFormat.parse not working since lollipop 5.0 Android update

Tags: android, date

I just installed the upgrade version Lollipop on my android phone and this doesn't work anymore:

```
String time = "Apr 07 10:35:27 CEST 2015";
long l1 = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy").parse(time).getTime();

long l2 = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy",
                Locale.ENGLISH).parse(time).getTime();
```

Both doesn't work:

```
W/System.err(11473): java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "avr. 07 10:35:27 CEST 2015" (at offset 17)
```

The problem is that SimpleDateFormat now returns GMT+02:00 instead of previously CEST after I installed 5.0

Comment: the posted code does not produce the given error. `avr.` is a/ french and b/ not a format recognized by the `MMM` token. `Avr` would, if you pass Locale.FRENCH to the formatter.

Comment: I'm on a french phone I don't know, anyway Locale.FRENCH doesn't solve anything. The problem is CEST became GMT+02:00 after I installed 5.0

Comment: where do you get that date from?

Comment: `CEST became GMT+02:00` I don't understand what you mean

Answer (score 1):

"CEST" is not a recognized timezone pattern according to [CLDR](http://www.unicode.org/cldr/charts/26/by_type/date_&_time.gregorian.html), which Android uses. It may be that it was recognized in prior because `SimpleDateFormat` was lifted from Apache Harmony, which followed Java's own time format standard.

Comment: So I should consider having only the "GMT+02:00" models and no more consider CEST at all ? My only objective is to get precision dates.

Comment: You may find this helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532729/daylight-saving-time-and-time-zone-best-practices